# Does it make sense to run mcelog inside of a kvm vm?

Tags: qemu, kvm, libvirt, mcelog

I would imagine it would catch qemu / kvm / libvirt bugs, and probably nothing related to the actual hardware. Running mcelog on the host of course, but is it worth it/helpful to run it inside a kvm vm also?